# Delete whitespace between two specific words in sed

Tags: sed, whitespace

The input is:

```
"At 12: 30 then"
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
echo "At 12: 30 then" | sed -e "/[0-9]\+:\(\s\+\)[0-9]\+/d"
```

The expected output is:

```
At 12:30 then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposition:

```
echo "At 12: 30 then" | sed "s/\([0-9]\+\)\s*:\s*\([0-9]\+\)/\1:\2/"
echo "At 12 : 30 then" | sed "s/\([0-9]\+\)\s*:\s*\([0-9]\+\)/\1:\2/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Careful there, the delete command in sed is within the context of a **line**, you probably need to substitute instead.

```
echo "At 12: 30 then" | sed -e "s/\([0-9]\+\):\(\s\+\)\([0-9]\+\)/\1:\3/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash escape forest can be avoided with `-E` (or also `-r` for GNU sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9]+:) *([0-9]+)/\1\2/' <<< 'At 12: 30 then'
At 12:30 then
```